# Porque a reputação decai sem motivo e não é indicado no perfil?

Tags: suporte, reputação

Tenho perdas de pontos de reputação sem motivos, e não são contabilizadas no perfil na aba de reputação. Porque isso ocorre? Estava em torno de 576 alguns dias atrás, depois caiu 3-4 pontos e essa semana mais 3-4 pontos, existe alguma perda de reputação por inatividade?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A reputação as vezes diminui por conta de publicações que são removidas onde vc tinha ganho algum ponto de reputação nelas por algum motivo. O fato de você não estar enxergando essas alterações de reputação no seu perfil é por que vc não tem o privilégio de ver publicações excluídas. Quando eu abro a sua aba de reputação eu vejo o seguinte:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você perdeu os 2 pontos que havia ganhado ao editar esses publicações que foram removidas.

Quem tiver o privilégio de ver as publicações removidas pode conferir por exemplo nessa pergunta: [Erro segmentation fault em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/388354/3117)

Para quem não tem o privilégio, aí vai a imagem que resume o que causou a alteração na sua reputação:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não deveria aparecer ao usuário essa informação também, mesmo não tendo reputação suficiente ? Afinal de contas é algo quem editou diretamente, e não mostrar parece-me uma solução pior a nível de UX. Como está dá a ideia de magia. Para além disso ainda torna clara a ideia de que editar publicações muito fracas é pouco produtivo uma vez que podem ser eliminadas quer seja pela comunidade, moderadores ou o próprio autor.

Comment: Tb acho importante que aparecesse, mas acho que o pessoal da empresa não se importa muito com isso vide essa pergunta de 2012: [Strange change in reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142130/229289). Não achei nenhum tópico recente (talvez eu não tenha procurado direito), mas acho q a prioridade da empresa quanto a isso continua a mesma até os dias de hoje.