# Reputação diminuindo gradativamente

Tags: suporte

Após os pontos adicionais que todos recebemos, eu fiquei com 260 de reputação.
 
Hoje, após uns dias sem utilizar o SOpt, acesso a página e então noto que perdi 4 pontos de reputação, sendo que não recebi nenhum voto negativo, e minhas perguntas no SOpt não foram acessadas. Porque isto acontece?

Comment: Tenta ver aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/124573/riki481?tab=reputation

Comment: Relacionado: [Porque a reputação decai sem motivo e não é indicado no perfil?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7837/3117)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Olhando [sua reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/124573/riki481?tab=reputation) consta duas perguntas que fez edição e ganhou pontos por isso, e elas foram removidas do site, então os pontos se foram junto.

Comment: Entendo, então funciona da mesma forma que perguntas feitas por mim. Pensei que havia algum algoritmo no site que diminuía os pontos de reputação caso a pessoa parasse de acessar a página.